Parsing the XML in Powershell: Escaping various symbols in XPath
I need to parse the VS2022 .vbproj file to find the details of build configuration.
In powershell, I load the file and try to get to the necessary node. But I'm stuck with misleading PS error reporting and overwhelming amount of special symbols to escape...
I am looking for that line from .vbproj:
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">

here is my script:
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $xmlFile)

$propertyGroup = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//PropertyGroup[@Condition= ""''`$(Configuration)|`$(Platform)'' == ''Debug|AnyCPU''""]")
if ($propertyGroup) {
    Write-Host 'Element found.'
} else {
    Write-Host 'Element not found.'
}

Whatever I do, I either get either syntax errors, or "Element not found"... Please help!

Could it be a namespace-issue? Try to change //PropertyGroup to //*[name()='PropertyGroup']

You could consider handling the .vbproj content not as XML, but as a simple collection of string lines. Then you wouldn't have to deal with XML escapes, but could simply search for your target patterns with a regex filter. There is of course no guarantee that the .vbproj files have a well-defined line structure, but in reality they do.

thanks for replies. @SiebeJongebloed, that is just an issue of properly escaping the single, reverse and double quotes along with dollar sign, which must be done inside another (doublequoted) string of the XPath...

@Halfix, that's exactly what I was thinking from the beginning, but stupid AI advised " the easiest is to parse it in powershell"... Each time I touch the "almighty" powershell, I suffer hard and fallback to other means of doing things. I hoped today I will finally do it like microfosft recommends...

Use :
$xml.SelectSingleNode("//PropertyGroup[normalize-space(translate(@Condition,`"'$`",`"`"))='(Configuration)|(Platform) == Debug|AnyCPU']")

We escape " and $ characters and use translate function to do it only once.
Another option with contains and no escaping :
$xml.SelectSingleNode("//PropertyGroup[contains(@Condition,'(Configuration)') and contains(@Condition,'(Platform)') and contains(@Condition,'Debug') and contains(@Condition,'AnyCPU')]")


Bravo, thanks! Both variants work like a charm!
